# Rearranging a (list of lists) matrix using list comprehensions only

Tags: python, list, matrix, list-comprehension

Consider the following 3 x 4 matrix implemented as a list of 3 lists of length 4 in Python:

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

The following list comprehension will rearrange the matrix transposing rows and columns:

```
>>> [[row[i] for row in matrix] for i in range(4)]
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

BUT suppose I need this as result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

that is a 4 x 3 matrix rearranged so to obtain a sequential "scrolling" of the original matrix that "breaks" to a new row every 3 elements.

I know it is possible to draw out an algorithm to achieve the task but **would it be possible to obtain that using only list comprehensions?** (And, if yes, how?)

---

**EDIT:**

The accepted answer shall meet the following requirements:

- must work on a base/clean Python installation (no additional libraries);
- must be (similarly as for matrix transposition) a "one-liner".

---

**2nd EDIT + accepted answer motivation:**

Here's what I did when I had to find a solution for this (based upon the suggestions I gave in my own comments below):

```
mat = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]

[[mat[(3*(i-1)+j -1)//4+1][(3*(i-1)+j -1)%4] for j in range(3)] for i in range(4)]
```

*NOTE that the solution I wrote is specific to this case but, as Clodion noticed too, the "formula" can be "generalized" so to re-arrange the initial (list of lists) matrix to different "shapes".*

Comment: @Clodion (that asked for suggestions) and to who may need or be interested, what I know is: naming `ir , ic` the _total numbers of initial matrix rows and cols_, `i , j` the _indexes for the initial matrix rows and cols_ and `r , c` the _indexes for the re-arranged one_, having `k = ic*(i-1)+j`, the "indexes remapping formulas" will be `r = (k-1) // ir + 1` and `c = (k-1) % ir + 1`. P.S. note that `c` could be remmapped also in this way: `c = (j % ic if j % ic > 0 else i)`.

Comment: So, in this case: `ir=3`, `ic=4`, `k = 4*(i-1)+j`, `r = (k-1) // 3 + 1` and `c = (k-1) % 3 + 1` (or even `c = (j % 4 if j % 4 > 0 else i)`).

Comment: P.S. getting the original matrix number of rows and colons can be done, respectively, with: `len(mat)` and `len(mat[0])`

Comment: P.P.S. Obviously what I really meant was _columns_, **not** _colons_, in my last comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12]]
>>> it = (y for x in matrix for y in x)
>>> list(zip(*[it]*3))
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)]
```

If you want list of lists:

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12]]
>>> it = (y for x in matrix for y in x)
>>> list(map(list, zip(*[it]*3)))
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Explanation:

1. First we create a generator that gives the elements of the list (as if it were flattened to a single list - that is 1,2,3,4,5,6,...,12) - we store that in `it`.
2. Then we call `zip()` giving it `it` three times; since the generator is the same, it provides a next element in `it` every time.

FURTHER NOTE: you can even re-arrange the initial matrix in different "shapes" than the 4 x 3, if you want, by simply changing the `3` to the desired number of columns. (For example, change it to `2` or to `6` and you'll obtain, respectively, a 6 x 2 or a 2 x 6 re-arranged matrix instead).

---

A method without using `zip` , and only using list comprehension, but it requires two lines -

```
>>> matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12]]
>>> it = (y for x in matrix for y in x)
>>> [[next(it) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(4)]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: OP said: `would it be possible to obtain that using only list comprehensions?` no?

Comment: I am guessing the aim of it was that he did not want to draw out an complex algorithm to do it. Thats what I get from - ***I know it is possible to draw out an algorithm to achieve the task** BUT would it be possible to obtain that using only list comprehensions?*

Comment: Also, The thing I am doing with `map()` can be very easily achieved with list comprehension, but I think `map()` suits its more.

Comment: Whoa! I'm very positively impressed by your solution that, since you can practically make it a one liner this way: `list(zip(*[(y for x in matrix for y in x)]*3))`, also is the only one meeting all requirements at the moment (I edited my question). Could you provide even a solution that resembles the transposition way? It would only be a "plus" (just out of curiosity) to see if possible, anyway I like the use of zip/map, too. 8-)

Comment: Sorry , I didn't understand what you mean't by the transposition way, do you mean the matrix transposition you showed in your question? If not, can you help me understand with an example?

Comment: Yes, the transposition example showed in my question (I should have write "example" instead of "way"... sorry!)

Comment: This - `[[next(it) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(4)]` ? Updated in my answer.

Comment: I think your first approach (zip/map) is GREAT! I couldn't but accept yours as the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Is numpy an option?

```
import numpy

x = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
y = numpy.array(x).reshape((4, 3))
print y
```

Output:

```
[[ 1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9]
 [10 11 12]]
```

Here's at least a list comprehension, I'm lacking creativity right now but this does the trick somewhat :P

```
print [[[z for y in x for z in y][i*3+j] for j in range(len(x))] for i in range(len(x[0]))]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: Please see my question edit and comments beneath.
Unfortunately NumPy can't be imported if its library package isn't installed before... yet, your NumPy solution would be a nice one-liner :-)

Comment: P.S. : I admit I never used NumPy so far, so I'm wondering, is that output "real"? I mean, aligned stacked values and no commas?

Comment: @danicotra: yes, it is. That's the way numpy prints it's results by default. The way you would expect from mathematical matrices.

Comment: @danicotra: now it's a one-liner btw :)

Comment: Whoa... Cool! Isn't it? :-D

Answer (score 2):

The following solution uses only list comprehensions, and no zip:

```
m = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12]]

flat = [l2 for l1 in m for l2 in l1]
output = [[flat.pop(0), flat.pop(0), flat.pop(0)] for x in range(4)]

print(output)
```

Output is:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Or for a very simple one liner:

```
print [m[0][:3],[m[0][3]]+m[1][0:2],m[1][2:]+[m[2][0]],m[2][1:]]
```

Comment: I edited my question providing requirements to accept the answer (and some comments beneath too). Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Well, with lists only, it's crude (suggestions will be appreciated?):

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12]]
lst = [y for row in matrix for y in row]
lst = [[lst[x+y*3] for x in range(3)] for y in range(4)]
print(lst)
```

Result:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Yes! In one list comprehension:

```
nr, nc = 4, 3
ic = len(matrix[0])
lst = [[matrix[(r*nc+c)//ic][(r*nc+c)%ic] for c in range(nc)] for r in range(nr)]
print(*lst, sep="\n")
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
[7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12]
```

But you can also have (with `nr, nc = 6, 2`)

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
[7, 8]
[9, 10]
[11, 12]
```

That's your question, no?

Comment: Please see my question edit and comments beneath, maybe you'll find something useful as suggestions?

Comment: @danicotra: yes, I've read it, but I think is too complex for me. But it give me ideas!. I've edited my answer to have only one comprehension list.

Comment: Yeah, I see you got it, nice "generalized" solution :-)